# Hover for touchscreens

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

The site I am making has a hover menu, what is best practice to deal with this for touchscreens. How can I get it to work on mobile devices?

I googled this and some responses suggest:

```
 :active
```

So I tried a quick [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6aejkv5/1/) on an iPhone, but it doesn't appear to work.

Whats the correct way to tackle this and why does my fiddle not work?

Also is there a CSS only solution?

Comment: `:active` is only valid on `a` elements.

Comment: Ah thanks, what should I do for mobile then?

Comment: You can add `onclick=""` to hovered element. Hover will work after that.

Comment: Use `:hover`, `:active`. `.one:hover, .one:active { blah:blah }`.

Comment: Or using `:focus` whenever you use `:hover` Like: `.test:hover, .test:focus`.

Comment: I updated my fiddle for focus but it fails on mobile.

Comment: You need to play with touchstart and touchend events in mobile..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For obvious reasons, the hover behavior doesn't work on touch devices. The most apparent solution is to make your menus activate on click, and if that's the case, I would recommend making that standard behavior for the desktop version as well. There's a case to made against hover menus because they just aren't as usable: http://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-hover-menus-do-users-more-harm-than-good/

Comment: Thanks, would love to make it all on click but im not the designer!